# AbstractClass Junit with Autowired annotation

Tags: java, spring, junit, mocking, mockito

I have an abstract class which uses @Autowired annotation inside it.
I am trying to write the junit using MockitoJUnitRunner.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class AbstractAdminSearchServiceTest {

 @Mock
 private IUPSService upsService;

 Map<String,String> map;

  @Before
    public void setUp() {
      map=new HashMap<>();
    }

 @Test
 public void testSearchAdministratorsForIndividualNotification(){
     AbstractAdminSearchService 
 mock=Mockito.mock(AbstractAdminSearchService.class,
             Mockito.CALLS_REAL_METHODS);
     when(upsService.getUsersProfile(buildUserIds(),new String[] 
{})).thenReturn(map);
     mock.searchAdministratorsForIndividualNotification(buildSolrUsers(), 
"");

 }
```

@Mock is not working and 'upsService' is not getting mocked.
As a result when actually upsService.getUsersProfile is called,i am getting NullpointerException.

Comment: You are mocking a class and expect that to be auto wired... That isn't going to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically we will not write Junits for abstract classes, Because we can't create object for them,If it is a normal concrete class instead of
 below code

```
mock=Mockito.mock(AbstractAdminSearchService.class,
Mockito.CALLS_REAL_METHODS);
```

use

```
@InjectMocks
private AbstractAdminSearchService mock;
```

and then all mocks will be inserted into real object

Comment: Yes thats true,but my abstract class has got a concrete method,so how do we Junit that?

Comment: we can cover those concrete methods in abstract class while writing Junit for child classes